# Create hybrid desktop and web application with different languages

Tags: javascript, java, web-applications, desktop-application

I want to create an app to estimate engineering costs: lots of tables, forms, a sidebar with a tree structure and so on. You can access a database in the cloud and create table structures according to records in the database.

Naturally that would be a website, however, if the user does not always have an access to the Internet, he/she can download a copy of that database (precisely, a copy of the current version of the database), so that it would be possible to get data from it and work locally. That is why an offline desktop app is needed.

Would it be possible to develop such a hybrid application without first creating a web app and then doing the same with a desktop app?

Previously i have looked into JavaFX, but we saw that it's too difficult to create a website out of that. Then we saw Electron, but i'm not sure if it is the right choice, because it seams that Electron is only used for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm lost as to why you feel you need a website/desktop hybrid. There are many APIs available to let you access a cloud database. All you have to do is find an API with web hooks, or APIs that specifically target the database type you are using (sql, mongo, or whatever). Then just cache a local copy once you've pulled down the database.

Work on the copy then push back to the database when they save, or try to do a push/pull every 5 minutes or something.

Comment: you can cache it but where would you use that copy if you don't have a desktop software.

Comment: Ah, I see. I feel like the question was not clear. I was under the impression that you wanted one application that had the functionality of accessing an online database, but available offline, not two versions of a similar application (one for cloud web use, one for desktop).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a HTML page, which would:

- Use AJAX calls if connected
- Add relative `<script>` tag, thinking that HTML file lies in a folder on PC, and that script is somewhere nearbly.

In both cases, user will get same results.
Downloads are:

- HTML file with inline script
- JS file with database

or

- zipped folder with HTML, database JS files and all scripts, images, css, etc. requred for HTML file to show properly.

Comment: User will need only browser and arciever.